# How do I insert special character as the result of case_when in R Shiny?

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I have this code I put in R Shiny :

```
case_when(tesdata$note <= 10 ~ "&#8804",
tesdata$note > 10 ~ "&#8805")
```

It should return ≤ if the value is less than or equal to 10 and ≥ if the value is more than 10.

However it won't give me the special character and instead return the code itself `"&#8804"`.

How do I make it return the special character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unicode equivalent.

```
testdata %>% 
  mutate(
    newcolumn = case_when(
      note <= 10 ~ "\u2264",  # ≤
      note > 10  ~ "\u2265",  # ≥
      TRUE       ~ "\u2245"   # ≅
    )
  )
```